# Get all elements of an element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I've got this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <record ID="#046CE9401D01467B2BDBAF0" NumDoc="1461">
        <NAME>
            <P>Pedrito De Rosa</P>
            <P>NIE X1111222233</P>
            <P>tf 2283396922</P>
            <P>efael@hostmailer.com</P>
        </NAME>
        <ADDRESS>
            <P>Paseo Jauregizahar 234 &#45; 1&#46; A&#46; Donostia </P>
        </ADDRESS>
        <SUBJECT>
            <P>paisaje y ciudad </P>
        </SUBJECT>
        <QUERYS>
            <P>2014-12-10 Avance Normas Subsidiarias</P>
            <P>Otras consultas</P>
        </QUERYS>
    </record>
</root>
```

I'm trying to read this XML and insert the values into a mysql table (NAME,ADDRESS,SUBJECT,QUERYS). The problem is when I try to read for example a NAME field like this:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data/data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
records = tree.findall('record')
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    myname = record.find("NAME/P")
    print (myname.text)
```

The output with this code is "Pedrito De Rosa" instead of all the content . I mean, it should get all the P elements within "NAME" tags, otherwise we are losing data...

How can I get all the data within elements? I tried with record.findAll("NAME/P") but there is no findAll method.

Any help or clue?

I created a pyfiddle if anyone can help... 
https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/9ed9743d-4d6e-4400-bfb5-19ba2bbf65f7/?i=true

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
records = tree.findall('record')
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    myname = record.findall("NAME/P")

    for item in myname:
        print (item.text)
```

output:

```
Pedrito De Rosa
NIE X1111222233
tf 2283396922
efael@hostmailer.com
```

Comment: oh! I was trying all the time with findAll

Answer (score 1):

With flexible `element.xpath` function:

```
...
root = tree.getroot()

records = tree.findall('record')
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    names = record.xpath("NAME/P/text()")
    print(names)

    addresses = record.xpath("ADDRESS/P/text()")
    print(addresses)

    subjects = record.xpath("SUBJECT/P/text()")
    print(subjects)

    querys = record.xpath("QUERYS/P/text()")
    print(querys)
```

The output:

```
['Pedrito De Rosa', 'NIE X1111222233', 'tf 2283396922', 'efael@hostmailer.com']
['Paseo Jauregizahar 234 - 1. A. Donostia ']
['paisaje y ciudad ']
['2014-12-10 Avance Normas Subsidiarias', 'Otras consultas']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
I choose to regex to get the name from XML.

**Code :**

```
import re

line = "<NAME><P>Pedrito De Rosa</P></NAME>"
matchObj = re.search( r'.*NAME..P.(.*)..P...NAME', line, re.M|re.I)
if matchObj:
    print("Name : ", matchObj.group(1))
```

**Output :**

```
Name :  Pedrito De Rosa
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

elements = ['NAME','ADDRESS','SUBJECT','QUERYS']
data = {}
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <record ID="#046CE9401D01467B2BDBAF0" NumDoc="1461">
        <NAME>
            <P>Pedrito De Rosa</P>
            <P>NIE X1111222233</P>
            <P>tf 2283396922</P>
            <P>efael@hostmailer.com</P>
        </NAME>
        <ADDRESS>
            <P>Paseo Jauregizahar 234 &#45; 1&#46; A&#46; Donostia </P>
        </ADDRESS>
        <SUBJECT>
            <P>paisaje y ciudad </P>
        </SUBJECT>
        <QUERYS>
            <P>2014-12-10 Avance Normas Subsidiarias</P>
            <P>Otras consultas</P>
        </QUERYS>
    </record>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for e in elements:
  lst = root.find('.//record/{}'.format(e)).getchildren()
  data[e] =  [x.text for x in lst]
```